# HTML5 working fine in chrome but not editable in mozilla

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<input type="text"
  min="1"
  max="99"
  pattern="[0-9]*"
  class="form-control"
  maxlength="2"
  id="page_cnt"
  onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
```

I am using bootstrap and html 5 attributes. It's working fine in chrome browser but its not editable in Mozilla browser. The below Input code is not working in mozilla browser.
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: <input type="text" min="1" max="99" pattern="[0-9]*" class="form-control" maxlength="2" id="page_cnt" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>

Comment: Please edit your question, unclear what you are asking.